# $(...).gantt is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, gantt-chart

I want to display some gantt-charts on my website, but they won't show up. Instead I get a TypeError.

The Site (not fully shown):

```
<body>
   {% block body %}
       <div class="container">
          <div class="gantt" id="gantt"></div>
          //... some stuff (only <div></div> and some <span></span> tags)
          <div class="gantt" id="gantt2"></div>
          //... even more stuff
          <div class="gantt" id="gantt3"></div>
       </div>
   {% endblock %}

   //Here I include the jquery.fn.gantt.js, etc.
   {% block javascripts %}
        {% javascripts '@jquery_js' '@bootstrap_js' '@jquery_gantt' combine=true       %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        <script>
            $("#gantt").gantt({
                source: [{
                    name: "Example",
                    desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
                    values: [{
                            from: "/Date(1333411200000)/",
                            to: "/Date(1328832000000)/",
                            label: "Example Value",
                            desc: "Something",
                            customClass: "ganttRed"}]
                    }],
               scale: "weeks",
               minScale: "hours",
               navigate: "scroll"
           });
           $("#gantt1").gantt({
               source: [{... same as above ...}],
               scale: "weeks",
               minScale: "hours",
               navigate: "scroll"
           });
           $("#gantt2").gantt({
               source: [{... same as above ...}],
               scale: "weeks",
               minScale: "hours",
               navigate: "scroll"
           });
        </script>
        {% endjavascripts %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

and the config.yml:

```
jquery_js:
    inputs:
        - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.js'
        - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js'
bootstrap_js:
    inputs:
        - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'
jquery_gantt:
    inputs:
        - '%kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/js/jquery.fn.gantt.js'
        - '%kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/js/jquery.fn.gantt.min.js'
```

If I run this code now, nothing happens except that this error appears:

```
TypeError: $(...).gantt is not a function
```

I don't know what's happening or how to fix this, as everything seems correct to me. the .js/.css-files are included and load correctly.

Comment: The solution (not fully given): add the `jquery.fn.gantt.js` again before you call the function, and after you have loaded jQuery.

Comment: Make sure `jquery.fn.gantt.js` is loaded when you try to execute your code, e.g. use $.ready: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: provide full code to show how you include gantt.js file

Comment: jQuery loading fine ? Try they're demo code maybe ?

Comment: jQuery and the .gantt plugin are loading fine (thanks to assetic), tried $.ready() already, but it haven't worked.

Comment: Have you ensured that Symfony is loaded *after* jQuery initializes?

Comment: Yep, otherwise my bootstrap would fail

Comment: @PeterDarmis I added the assetic-part, which handles the inclusion of the jquery and it's .gantt plugin.